# xCode trying to login using MySQL

Tags: php, ios, mysql, xcode

I am really new to swift and i'm trying to make my first app. So I have a databace that has my web user's accouts on, Now I'm trying to make an app that uses the same databace as the website but I can't find any new/good tutorial to help me as most of the ones I have tryed are outdated.

Question - What's the best way to connect an app to a MySQL databace and do you know of any good tutorials that could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can write down web services (APIs) that can send and receive data from your server (where your database lies) to your mobile app. 
This is the way you can use same database in both web and mobile apps.

You can use JSON or XML format in your web services to communicate with mobile apps. I would prefer/suggest you to use JSON.

You can further study on it, That how you can write web services for mobile apps?

This is the direction where you can forward to make things work and done.